# How do I go about understanding particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, education

My science project has tasked me in creating a research paper on the standard model of particle physics, but I'm not in highschool yet. I don't know how to go about learning the math and the concepts involved in the standard model. Can anyone help an aspiring scientist?